# multiple conditions in numpy.where

Tags: python, numpy

With some numpy array a, what I'd like to do is

```
indices = np.where((a < 4) or (a > 12))
```

This isn't valid. It just returns "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". But this expression *isn't* ambiguous, and `any` and `all` don't do what I want to do. (`any` and `all` can't take compound expressions either. But `if` can. Confused...)

Comment: `indices = np.where((a < 4) | (a > 12))` Aside: this is a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for the duplication; I couldn't find any related article. Apparently because this has nothing to do with `np.where()`, but rather the fact that Python has <i>both</i> `or` and `|` and they do different things. Oh, Python, you silly beast...

Comment: No problem. It is oft-times difficult to find duplicates. Those two operators do different things.

Comment: They are not the same operator...

Comment: Yes, hence my comment about them doing different things. Does Python finish the craziness and have both `and` and `&` too? EDIT: Yes, yes, it does. *sigh*

Answer (score 12):

You want to get a logical/boolean array as your argument for `where`

You can do `x | y` or `np.logical_or(x,y)` , where `x` and `y` are `a < 4` and `a > 12`